# how to list all keywords used by a robotframework test suite

Tags: python, robotframework

If a robotframework project has keywords that spreads out in several folders (e.g., in resource and library files), is there a utility to list all user-defined keywords along with the lower level keywords invoked ?

This utility is similar to how the 'cflow' utility parses all c source files and produce a database file.

Answer (score 3):

Using robot framework api we can get KEYWORD Metrics

Reference:[Link](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0.4/autodoc/robot.result.html)

API: class robot.result.model.Keyword

```
# Keyword Metrics Code: (save following snippet as python file and execute)
from robot.api import ExecutionResult,ResultVisitor

result = ExecutionResult('output.xml')
result.configure(stat_config={'suite_stat_level': 2,
                              'tag_stat_combine': 'tagANDanother'})

class KeywordMetrics(ResultVisitor):

    def visit_keyword(self,kw):
        print "Keyword Name: " + str(kw.name) 
        print "Keyword Status: " + str(kw.status)
        print "Keyword Starttime: " + str(kw.starttime)
        print "Keyword Endtime: " + " " + str(kw.endtime)
        print "Keyword Elapsedtime (Sec): " + " " + str(kw.elapsedtime/float(1000))

result.visit(KeywordMetrics())
```

[Robot framework Metrics](https://github.com/adiralashiva8/robotframework-metrics) project is implemented to show metrics result in HTML format with dashboard view.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tool. Though, you could write your own by creating a [listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) that records each keyword as it runs.

Comment: Great !. thanks for your suggestion. I could use the 'start_keyword' method.

Comment: Listener can be used although you need to execute Robot on testcase to get the results, in case of bigger project and tests which last a while it may take some time to get results (if all testcases are executed)

Answer (score 0):

In my mind this question can be answered two fold:

1. List all the keywords *used* in a Test Run. For this Bryan provided a good approach. An alternative approach is to look at the output.xml file, and use xpath or xquery to filter out the keywords that were used. Including the hierarchy.
2. List all the keywords *in* a particular folder, including it's sub folders. This probably contains more keywords then when solely run it also does not list the hierarchy when used.

If option 2 is the desired outcome, then familiarize yourself with the Robot Framework [LibDoc](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#libdoc) Library Documentation tool. Aside from libraries, you can also document resource robot files that contain your own keywords.

There are two output possibilities: HTML and XML. So, if your end goal is to pull certain information from the file for further processing, I'd recommend XML.

Comment: Thank you for the 2 options. For Option 1, the '--dryrun' option of pybot provides a quick a way of capturing all the keywords data nicely. I can then use xmllint or other tools to parse output.xml, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tool but can be made pretty quickly. Rflint has a parser,which can iterate over testsuites to get list of keywords and testcases used in robot file. If you can generate a structure that links keywords usage to testcases/testsuites,you will get at least stats from Robot defined KW.

Sample snipped from GitHub/RED, *parse_rf_file(parent_filename)* is a good starting point.
https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/misc/nilsimsa_POC/nilsimsa_POC.py

Rflint GitHub page: https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-lint